# Firebase analytics event parameters are not registered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, debugview

I am well acquainted with Firebase Analytics, I created some custom event with parameter "value" and send it this way:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value", "my_value");
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("my_event", bundle);
```

In DebugView I can see it collected. But after I send another event with different value (`my_value_2`, after 30 seconds during same session) it is collected with no parameter, only event `my_event`. If I restart the app and send event with `my_value_2` value param first, it is shown in DebugView, and then no params for more events again.

I double checked amount of parameters: I have 9 text params so it should be collected.

How can I fix this problem? Is there any limits of parameter values that user send during session?

Comment: While I'm not completely sure, the events that FirebaseAnalytics collect itself may count to the limitations you know (a.k.a 10 key-value pairs for events that has string values.) So, try to check all the events reported by the SDK with log tag **FA/SVC** (I think that was the tag, **FA** is definitely in it) and try to count the string values from there.

Comment: But yeah, I can confirm we're experiencing same issues on production, the event count is high but the values are not fetched enough.

Comment: The same problem occurred on my ios application. I do detect my parameter on debug view, but none of the parameter is collected in dash board...